# Spyder: Error occurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I am getting this error message in my Spyder console:

[image]

This happened after I changed the Python interpreter to my python 3.8 exe file since my Anaconda/Spyder was using 3.7. I tried to use conda install spyder-kernels in my anaconda prompt but it said that All requested packages already installed. Any way to fix this?

Comment: There is a distribution of spyder kernels for 3.8 on the anaconda site, you might have to be specific that spyder and the kernel are for 3.8 and not 3.7 https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/  then scroll

Comment: _I changed the Python interpreter to my python 3.8 exe file since my Anaconda/Spyder was using 3.7._ What exe? Couldn't you just update the packages? Are you using the base/root environment for development?